# Changing Opacity Using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

I have a page with an image background that I want to fade in after 2 seconds, but cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="neo_wrapper">
  <div id="neo_container">
    <div id="neo_homepage_image"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#neo_home_page {
width: 960px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
opacity: 0;
}

#neo_wrapper {  
width: 960px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#neo_container {    
width: 960px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

And JavaScript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {;
$("#neo_home_page").backstretch("_ui/bg_img.jpg");
});
</script>
<script>

var x = document.getElementById('neo_home_page');

setTimeout(function(){x.opacity = "1.0"}, 2000);

</script>
```

I have the opacity of the element I want to change initially set to 0, and want it to fade in after 2 seconds. My body ID is set to "neo_home_page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use animate

```
$(x).animate({opacity:1.0},2000);
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

Why you just use a transition, have a better performance and you can control the delay

```
#blah{
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color:red;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('blah').style.opacity = 1;
});
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/m4rE7/)

Answer (score 0):

As you have [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tagged, you can simply use [jQuery's `fadeIn` method](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) rather than trying to recreate the wheel:

```
$('#neo_home_page').fadeIn(2000);
```